# How do I get to the church in tuesday to confess my sins?

Tags: postal-2

I need to confess my sins in the church and the only way I've seen to get there is through the trainyard, But its blocked.
Is there any other way to pass it?
or did I missed something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Near the church are cargo containers blocking the street. Inspect the containers and you will find a hole which you can follow to the church.

Example at 5:06:

Comment: Oh snap, they made it really hard to spot.
anyway, thanks  a lot.